# Get inbox and folder message using AngularJS GraphSDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to get all the message in inbox but it is not working. I tried with [Microsoft Angular SDK reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mail_api_overview%20reference%20but%20no%20luck.)

MainController.js

```
    function getMessages() {

  authToken = localStorage.token;       

  // Build the HTTP request payload (the Message object).

  // Save email address so it doesn't get lost with two way data binding.
  vm.emailAddressSent = vm.emailAddress;
  GraphHelper.getMessages()
    .then(function (response) {
      $log.debug('HTTP request to the Microsoft Graph API returned successfully.', response);
      vm.requestSuccess = true;
      vm.requestFinished = true;
        $scope.data=response;
        vm.data=response;
      $scope.$apply();
    }, function (error) {
      $log.error('HTTP request to the Microsoft Graph API failed.');
      vm.requestSuccess = false;
      vm.requestFinished = true;
      $scope.$apply();
    });

};
```

GraphHelper.js

I changed graphHelper.js

```
getMessages: function getMessages(email) {
      return graphClient.api('/me/messages').get({ 'message' : email });
    }
```

Config.JS

```
var APPLICATION_CONFIG = {
clientID: "b73f88f7-2169-471f-9381-e9f098684140",
redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
interactionMode: "popUp",
graphEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages",
graphScopes: ["user.read mail.send Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite "]
};
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any error?

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: `graphClient.api(<url>).get()` returns a promise if you don't pass in a callback function. I believe the issue is that you are treating it as a promise in `maincontroller.js` but you're passing in an object to .get(). If you don't pass any arguments, what behavior do you see in `maincontroller.js`?

Comment: HI The exact problem is am not getting all the mailboxes.

Comment: I tried to get all the messages in inbox.but it is displayed only few messages. and also i am not able to filter the particular message in inbox